# How to only implement part of the parameters of the MultiParamTypeClasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt

How to write Haskell code like (with language extension `GADTs` and `MultiParamTypeClasses`):

```hs
class MyClass f a where
    func :: a -> f a
    
data MyData a where
    Cons1 :: a -> MyData a
    Cons2 :: MyData a
    
instance MyClass MyData a where
    func (Cons1 x) = -- implement func for (Cons1 x)
    
instance MyClass MyData Int where
    func Cons2 = -- implement func for Cons2 and don't need to implement func (Cons1 x)
    
instance MyClass MyData String where
    func Cons2 = -- implement func for Cons2 and don't need to implement func (Cons1 x)
```

So for different `a`, we don't have to repeat `func (Cons1 x)`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really related to classes at all. As usual, to share code, you just call a function that does the shared thing.

```
f1 (Cons1 x) = ...

f2 Cons2 = ...
f2 other = f1 other

f3 Cons2 = ...
f3 other = f1 other
```

This works whether `f2` and `f3` are class methods or not.